# In what context is the imperfective future tense "будет возвращаться" used?

Tags: значения, tense

- память **вернулась** к ним [<strike>his</strike> **their** memory (has) returned (at last)]
- память **возвращалась** к ним [<strike>his</strike> **their** memory was coming back (gradually)]
- память **возвращаемся** к ним [<strike>his</strike> **their** memory is coming back (gradually)]
- память **вернётся** к ним [<strike>his</strike> **their** memory will return (someday)]

I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of the imperfective future tense.

- память **будет возвращаться** к ним

Comment: Note that 'к ним' is 'to them', and 'to him' ('his memory' in these examples) would be 'к нему'

Comment: just as the imperfective Past is **was coming back** so the imperfective Future is **will be coming back**

Answer (score 7):

That corresponds to Future Progressive in English: The memory will be coming back to them.

Answer (score 2):

The context part of the question hasn't been addressed yet, so here're some examples

> Когда *будешь возвращаться* домой, купи хлеба.
>
> Завтра он *будет возвращаться* с соревнований, и мы (по)едем его встречать.
>
> Мы *будем возвращаться* с дачи на машине, так что (c)можем тебя подвезти.
>
> Мы этот вопрос уже обсудили, и я *не буду* к нему *возвращаться*.

So Future imperfective denotes being in the process of action or action being in the process of performance before completion.

Connotation in the last example is more complex due to negation. Here the imperfective aspect rather means repeated return than a process of return.

With the word **память** used in the question:

> Не волнуйтесь, память будет к вам постепенно возвращаться <sup>*prognosis by a doctor after memory loss*</sup>

Comment: "Когда будешь возвращаться домой" Does this mean "when you are on your way home, when you are returning home"?

Comment: @Segwayinto yes, that's correct